# Hive Concat function not working in Beeline

Tags: hive, concatenation, special-characters, string-concatenation, beeline

```
${beeline_url} --silent=true --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --showWarnings=false -e "select concat('invalidate metadata ', trim(table_name) , '; refresh ', trim(table_name) ,';') from my_Table " > /home/table_list.csv
```

I'm trying to run this query ends up with error. The same query runs fine in hive, hue and even with beeline.

while using beeline, the below query gave results

```
0: jdbc:hive2://host> select concat("invalidate metadata ", trim(table_name)) from my_Table;
```

I tried storing the query in a file but it ends up in error.

```
${beeline_url} --silent=true --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 --verbose=false --showWarnings=false -f get_table_list.hql > /home/table_list.csv
```

where get_table_list.hql  has

```
SELECT (CONCAT('invalidate metadata ', trim(table_name) , '; refresh ', trim(table_name) ,';')) from my_table;
```

Error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
>   1:59 cannot recognize input near '' '' '' in select
>   expression (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons need to be shielded using `\\`:

```
SELECT (CONCAT('invalidate metadata ', trim(table_name) , '\\; refresh ', trim(table_name) ,'\\;')) from my_table;
```

Or replace them with  `\073`:

```
SELECT (CONCAT('invalidate metadata ', trim(table_name) , '\073 refresh ', trim(table_name) ,'\073')) from my_table;
```

One of these workarounds should work.